# How to fix arm-none-eabi-objcopy: error: the input file 'led' has no sections

Tags: gcc, arm

```
makefile:
led.hex: led
@echo 'Invoking: GNU ARM Cross Create Flash Image'
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex "led"  "led.hex"
@echo 'Finished building: $@'
@echo ' '
```

build message:

> Invoking: GNU ARM Cross Create Flash Image
>   arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex "led"  "led.hex"
>   arm-none-eabi-objcopy: error: the input file 'led' has no sections
>   make: *** [makefile:50: led.hex] Error 1
>   "make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

Comment: the input file 'led.elf' has no sections    i dont unserstand it,i am a beginner，i cant Google，help me,please

Comment: What kind of file is `led`? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i give up,i will use arm-linux-gcc on Linux,still thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I Also Got in same problem with my STM32F401RE Board , The simplest way out of it was to avoid using multiple  `.c` files in the project.